# cs50 PSET2 Substitution: Trouble only in encrypts all alphabetic characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key

Tags: c, cs50, substitution

I'm a beginner in cs50. This is my work on week2. This is problem set substitution.

so this is my code. All problems are compiled successfully except this one. The output is "Segmentation fault"

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])

{
    string key1 = argv[1];

//check for only 2 arguments//
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    return 1;
}

//check key length, must 26 lenght//
if (strlen(key1) != 26)
{
    printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
    return 1;
}

for (int i=0; i < strlen(key1); i++)
{
    //check for non alphabet//
    if (!(isalpha(key1[i])))
    {
        printf("Key must contain only letters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //convert all word to uppercase to make encryption easier//
    else
    {
        key1[i] = toupper (key1[i]);
    }

    //check for not repeated word//
    for (int j=0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (key1[i] == key1[j])
        {
            printf("Key must not contain repeated letters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

//ask input//
string input1 = get_string("plaintext: ");
string input2 = input1;

//check if the word is lower or uppercase//
int checker[25];
for (int s = 0; s < strlen (input1); s++)
{
    if (isupper(input1[s]) == 0)
    {
        checker[s] = 0; //false

        //convert to uppercase to make encryption easier//
        input1[s] = toupper (input1[s]);
    }
    else
    {
        checker[s] = 1; //true
    }

    //printf("Input %d: %c is %d\n", s, input1[s], checker[s]); //debug//

}

//printf("word is %s\n", input1); //debug//

//CONVERTTTT//
int new_ascii = 0;
printf("ciphertext: ");

for (int k = 0; k < strlen(input1); k++)
{
    char x = input1[k];
    int ascii = (int) x;

    //check if it's alphabet or not//
    if (isalpha(x))
    {
        ascii -=  65;
        new_ascii = key1[ascii];

        //restore to upper/lowercase
        if (checker[k]==0)
        {
           new_ascii = (int) tolower ((char) new_ascii); //we use tolower cause all word has converted to upper
        }

    }
    else //if not just continue
    {
        new_ascii = ascii;
    }

    printf("%c", (char) new_ascii);
}

printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
./substitution DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM

plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Segmentation fault
```

I don't know where's my problem since this is the only one can't be compiled. Does anyone have clue?

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger. Set breakpoints in your code at places where you think the problem might be occurring, and step through the code until you find out what's going wrong. I guarantee you'll learn more this way than by having someone here dive in and fix your code for you. (In any case, with no evidence of debugging efforts, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. As general rule, don't use magic numbers: `ascii -=  65;` If you mean `'A'` then use `'A'`, not `65`.

Comment: `int checker[25];` Where do you get `25` from? How does it relate to your 44 character long input string?

Comment: Not related: `string input2 = input1;` this does not create a copy of the string but only a copy of the pointer. Not sure if you want this. `(int) tolower ((char) new_ascii);` the casts are nonsense. The function takes an `int` and returns an `int`. Your casts are useless in best case and hide some errors in worst case.

Comment: Small reminder: From [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Post the question and respond to feedback. After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments."

Comment: StackOverflow only works if you provide feedback regarding comments and answers. Otherwise your post is useless for anyone searching for solution to same problem.

Answer (score 1):

(Unfortunately I could not reproduce the Segmentation fault on onlinegdb.com.)

**The size of the array `checker` must be at least the string length of the input.** This is problematic because you don't know how long the input will be. **Your example input is longer than the size 25 of the array, so your code will write past the end of the array and (try to) overwrite whatever is stored at this memory location.** This can result in a segmentation fault.

To avoid this out-of-bounds access to the array you could check the length of the input string and either truncate it or print an error message that informs the user about the limitation.

A better solution would be to integrate the check for uppercase/lowercase in the function that encrypts the input. With this approach you have to know the uppercase/lowercase information only for the character just being processed, not for all characters of the input string.

As this is a task for learning, I don't show a ready-made solution but only an algorithm as pseudo code:

```
for all characters of the input string
{
    get the next character

    if alphabetic (or better if it is in range 'A'..'Z' or 'a'..'z')
    {
        if lowercase
        {
            set lowercase flag
            key index = character - 'a'
        }
        else
        {
            clear lowercase flag
            key index = character - 'A'
        }

        get encrypted character based on key index

        if lowercase flag
        {
            convert to lowercase
        }

        print encrypted character
    }
    else /* not alphabetic */
    {
        print original character
    }
}
```

Note that the result of function `isalpha` depends on your locale settings. For languages other than English, additional characters might be classified as alphabetic ones. This could result in an out-of-bounds access to your key array. To avoid this you could add a check for `isascii` or use explicit checks for `'A'`..`'Z'` or `'a'`..`'z'`.